# Efficient floating point scaling in C++

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, trigonometry

I'm working on my fast (and accurate) sin implementation in C++, and I have a problem regarding the efficient angle scaling into the `+- pi/2` range.

My sin function for +-pi/2 using Taylor series is the following
(Note: FLOAT is a macro expanded to float or double just for the benchmark)

```
/**
 * Sin for 'small' angles, accurate on [-pi/2, pi/2], fairly accurate on [-pi, pi]
 */
// To switch between float and double
#define FLOAT float

FLOAT
my_sin_small(FLOAT x)
{
    constexpr FLOAT C1 = 1. / (7. * 6. * 5. * 4. * 3. * 2.);
    constexpr FLOAT C2 = -1. / (5. * 4. * 3. * 2.);
    constexpr FLOAT C3 = 1. / (3. * 2.);
    constexpr FLOAT C4 = -1.;
    // Correction for sin(pi/2) = 1, due to the ignored taylor terms
    constexpr FLOAT corr = -1. / 0.9998431013994987;

    const FLOAT x2 = x * x;

    return corr * x * (x2 * (x2 * (x2 * C1 + C2) + C3) + C4);
}
```

So far so good... The problem comes when I try to scale an arbitrary angle into the +-pi/2 range. My current solution is:

```
FLOAT
my_sin(FLOAT x)
{
    constexpr FLOAT pi = 3.141592653589793238462;
    constexpr FLOAT rpi = 1 / pi;

    // convert to +-pi/2 range
    int n = std::nearbyint(x * rpi);

    FLOAT xbar = (n * pi - x) * (2 * (n & 1) - 1);
    // (2 * (n % 2) - 1) is a sign correction (see below)
    return my_sin_small(xbar);
};
```

I made a [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/XXCyvo61aiSF64O1XAMiiZuYKQI), and I'm losing a lot for the +-pi/2 scaling.
Tricking with int(angle/pi + 0.5) is a nope since it is limited to the int precision, also requires +- branching, and i try to avoid branches...
What should I try to improve the performance for this scaling? I'm out of ideas.

Benchmark results for float. (In the benchmark the angle could be out of the validity range for my_sin_small, but for the bench I don't care about that...):
[image: performance]

Benchmark results for double.
[image: performance 2]

Sign correction for xbar in my_sin():
[image: sign correction]

Algo accuracy compared to python sin() function:
[image: accuracy]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243979/discussion-on-question-by-simre-efficient-floating-point-scaling-in-c).

Comment: Taylor series at `a` are not a good method for approximating functions at points different from `a`. Picking a Chebyshev based method or Remez is better.

Answer (score 2):

Candidate improvements

- Convert the radians `x` to *rotations* by dividing by 2*pi.
- Retain only the fraction so we have an angle (-1.0 ... 1.0).  This simplifies the OP's *modulo* step to a simple "drop the whole number" step instead.  Going forward with different angle units simply involves a co-efficient set change.  No need to scale back to radians.
- For positive values, subtract 0.5 so we have (-0.5 ... 0.5) and then flip the sign. This centers the possible values about 0.0 and makes for better convergence of the approximating polynomial as compared to the math *sine* function.  For negative values - see below.
- Call `my_sin_small1()` that uses this (-0.5 ... 0.5) rotations range rather than [-pi ... +pi] radians.
- In `my_sin_small1()`, fold constants together to drop the `corr *` step.
- Rather than use the truncated Taylor's series, use a more optimal set.  IMO, this will provide better answers, especially near +/-pi.

Notes: No `int` to/from `float` code.  With more analysis, possible to get a better set of coefficients that fix `my_sin(+/-pi)` closer to 0.0.  This is just a quick set of code to demo less FP steps and good potential results.

---

C like code for OP to port to C++

```
FLOAT my_sin_small1(FLOAT x) {
  static const FLOAT A1 = -5.64744881E+01;
  static const FLOAT A2 = +7.81017968E+01;
  static const FLOAT A3 = -4.11145353E+01;
  static const FLOAT A4 = +6.27923581E+00;
  const FLOAT x2 = x * x;
  return x * (x2 * (x2 * (x2 * A1 + A2) + A3) + A4);
}

FLOAT my_sin1(FLOAT x) {
  static const FLOAT pi = 3.141592653589793238462;
  static const FLOAT pi2i = 1/(pi * 2);
  x *= pi2i;
  FLOAT xfraction = 0.5f - (x - truncf(x));
  return my_sin_small1(xfraction);
}
```

For negative values, use `-my_sin1(-x)` or like code to flip the sign - or add 0.5 in the above minus 0.5 step.

---

Test

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  for (int d = 0; d <= 360; d += 20) {
    FLOAT x = d / 180.0 * M_PI;
    FLOAT y = my_sin1(x);
    printf("%12.6f %11.8f  %11.8f\n", x, sin(x), y);
  }
}
```

Output

```
0.000000  0.00000000  -0.00022483
0.349066  0.34202013   0.34221691
0.698132  0.64278759   0.64255589
1.047198  0.86602542   0.86590189
1.396263  0.98480775   0.98496443
1.745329  0.98480775   0.98501128
2.094395  0.86602537   0.86603642
2.443461  0.64278762   0.64260530
2.792527  0.34202022   0.34183803
3.141593 -0.00000009   0.00000000
3.490659 -0.34202016  -0.34183764
3.839724 -0.64278757  -0.64260519
4.188790 -0.86602546  -0.86603653
4.537856 -0.98480776  -0.98501128
4.886922 -0.98480776  -0.98496443
5.235988 -0.86602545  -0.86590189
5.585053 -0.64278773  -0.64255613
5.934119 -0.34202036  -0.34221727
6.283185  0.00000017  -0.00022483
```

---

Alternate code below makes for better results near 0.0, yet might cost a tad more time.  OP seems more inclined to speed.

```
FLOAT xfraction = 0.5f - (x - truncf(x));

// vs.

FLOAT xfraction = x - truncf(x);
if (x >= 0.5f) x -= 1.0f;
```

---

[Edit]

Below is a better set with about 10% reduced error.

```
-56.0833765f
77.92947047f
-41.0936875f
6.278635918f
```

Comment: Wow thanks it gave me a nice speedup. But as I see you are using `+-pi` range, but around `+-pi` this Taylor series is inaccurate, you need more terms. That's why I limited it to +-pi/2 since with a few terms it is still pretty accurate, and it gives a smooth function, while +-pi does not. But thanks the `ftruncf` idea, I think I'll adapt that!

Comment: @simre "but around +-pi this Taylor series is inaccurate" --> The coefficients here are _near_ the Taylor series ones (once adjusted for the angle units) yet differ.  With another TBD set of coefficients, the largest error can be elsewhere than at +-pi, like maybe at +-pi/4 and +-0.75pi. It depends on our goals.  The ones here were just a first effort.  We do not need more terms, just different coefficients.

Comment: @simre "it gave me a nice speedup." --> how much?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

Spend more time (code) to reduce the range to ±pi/4 (±45 degrees), then possible to use only 3 or 2 terms of a polynomial that is like the usually Taylors series.

```
float sin_quick_small(float x) {
  const float x2 = x * x;
#if 0
  // max error about 7e-7
  static const FLOAT A2 = +0.00811656036940792f;
  static const FLOAT A3 = -0.166597759850666f;
  static const FLOAT A4 = +0.999994132743861f;
  return x * (x2 * (x2 * A2 + A3) + A4);
#else
  // max error about 0.00016
  static const FLOAT A3 = -0.160343346851626f;
  static const FLOAT A4 = +0.999031566686144f;
  return x * (x2 * A3 + A4);
#endif
}

float cos_quick_small(float x) {
  return cosf(x); // TBD code.
}

float sin_quick(float x) {
  if (x < 0.0) {
    return -sin_quick(-x);
  }
  int quo;
  float x90 = remquof(fabsf(x), 3.141592653589793238462f / 2, &quo);
  switch (quo % 4) {
    case 0:
      return sin_quick_small(x90);
    case 1:
      return cos_quick_small(x90);
    case 2:
      return sin_quick_small(-x90);
    case 3:
      return -cos_quick_small(x90);
  }
  return 0.0;
}

int main() {
  float max_x = 0.0;
  float max_error = 0.0;
  for (int d = -45; d <= 45; d += 1) {
    FLOAT x = d / 180.0 * M_PI;
    FLOAT y = sin_quick(x);
    double err = fabs(y - sin(x));
    if (err > max_error) {
      max_x = x;
      max_error = err;
    }
    printf("%12.6f %11.8f  %11.8f  err:%11.8f\n", x, sin(x), y, err);
  }
  printf("x:%.6f err:%.6f\n", max_x, max_error);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried `remquo`, but it was crazy slow... Most of the time is spent on the range reduction, not the Taylor series itself. sin_small is like 4-5x faster than `std::sin`, with double it is even faster. The main problem is the range reduction. And the builtin functions are slow. I have made some bit hacking on floats (Yep, dangerous like hell), but it gained only a few percents. Also I have doubts about that switch on performance... Btw it seems pretty clean. Do you have a benchmark on that compared to your previous attempt? I guess this will be much slower.. :/

Comment: @simre Will look later into a `remquo()` alternative.  The key take-way here is that by getting the sub-range down to +-pi/4 _somehow_, we can use fewer poly terms.  What is the acceptable precision for a `quick_sine()`?  I part in a thousand, a million, ...?

Comment: For now I'm happy with part in a thousand. For my use the angles should be small, so |x|<pi/4 is expected, and for +-pi/2 my polynomial is probably more accurate then needed. But I would like to have a general sin function too, and this is where the range reduction comes in and this is the really slow part. The accuracy can be fine tuned later with the proper polynomial which can affect the performance (more or less), so I call that part done. Now my real problem is the range reduction only. And the `std` functions are pretty slow, so I think need some "hacky" solution there.

Comment: @simre BTW, are the angles originating in radians, degrees or what in your real application?  Angle reduction simpler in degrees.

Comment: Radians of course. Degrees and other stuff are for children. :|  But this is just one extra multiplication to convert to anything you want. So this conversion is fixed and constant in time, you can't really do anything for that so it doesn't really matter what is the input for the algorithm.

Comment: @simre It depends on correctness - which is low priority in your app. Floating point mod 360 is possible to do _exactly_ and incur no error.  Mod 2π is not as π is irrational.  That is the gist of the referenced article.  If you really want speed, turn the angle into an integer type, mod there, and then use the remaining MSBbits to perform a table look up and the LSBits to integer interpolate.  Many possibilities.  Yet as the limits and goals are only roughly outlined, we can only optimize so much.  Good luck.